# Opening a directory as a file descriptor creating it if it does not exist

Tags: c, file, posix

Variables:

- `conf` of type `struct Conf` whose details are not relevant to this review stores the configuration data being read.
- `str` is a string containing the path of the directory the app uses to save data.

Code:

```
bool exist = 0;
if ((mkdir(str, 0755) && !(exist = errno == EEXIST)) || (Dir = open(str, O_DIRECTORY)) == -1) {
    perror(str);
    return errno;
}
if (exist) {
    const int fd = openat(Dir, ".Conf", O_RDONLY);
    if (fd != -1) {
        const ssize_t r = read(fd, &conf, sizeof(struct Conf));
        if (r < sizeof(struct Conf))
            r != -1 ? (void)memset(&conf, 0, r) : perror(".Conf");
        if (close(fd))
            perror(".Conf");
    } else if (errno != ENOENT)
        perror(".Conf");
}
```

The issue is I am not sure if this is the cleanest way to accomplish this task. The program relies on the `mkdir` system call failing to signal that the directory already exists. Is it good practice to *expect* a system call to fail?

Another issue is creating a `bool` variable to set somewhere and use as a condition elsewhere, was what I thought of as a quick hack to achieve the correct logic.

What is a cleaner way to achieve this?

Comment: You will get better reviews if you can present the full function, including the declarations (e.g. `Dir`, which is presently undeclared).

Comment: In a code review all code is relevant, including all declarations.

Comment: The normal rule is not to change code in a question when it has been answered, but I've accepted the edit to my answer to keep the two consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add a *lot* of declarations to get this anywhere near compilable:

```
struct Conf
{
    char a;
    unsigned char b;
};

#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int read_conf(const char *str, struct Conf conf)
{
    int Dir;
```

Beware of reading from file directly into a structure like this - any small change to structure layout (e.g. using different a compiler) will cause data corruption.

---

This line is hard to read, with its mix of conditionals and side-effects:

> ```
> if ((mkdir(str, 0755) && !(exist = errno == EEXIST)) || (Dir = open(str, O_DIRECTORY)) == -1) {
> ```

I recommend encapsulating this in a function that is similar to `open(str, O_CREAT)` (but creating a directory rather than a plain file).  Even if it's only used once, it makes the code much clearer to understand.

In any case, we need to close `Dir` once we're finished with it, so we're leaking the descriptor.

---

The `if (exist)` test seems pointless, as if the directory is newly-created, `openat()` will quickly fail with `ENOENT`.  Saving a single system-call is unlikely to provide a measurable benefit, so go with the simpler code.

It's usually simpler to deal with error cases first - if we can return early, that reduces indentation in subsequent code, and therefore reduces cognitive load.

---

There's some more confusing code:

```
        if (r < sizeof(struct Conf))
            r != -1 ? (void)memset(conf, 0, r) : perror(".Conf");
```

Much clearer if we unwrap that:

```
    if (r < 0) {
        perror(".Conf");
        goto err;
    }
    const size_t ur = (size_t)r;
    if (ur < sizeof conf) {
        memset(&conf, 0, ur);
        goto err;
    }

    ⋮

    int retval;
 err:
    retval = errno;
    close(fd);
    return retval;
```

It still doesn't make sense - why do we overwrite just the part the config we read?  And is all-bytes-zero appropriate for a `struct Conf`?

We should be continuing the read, like this:

```
static bool read_n(int fd, char *dest, size_t count)
{
    while (count) {
        ssize_t bytes_read = read(fd, dest, count);
        if (bytes_read <= 0) {
            return false;
        }
        dest += bytes_read;
        count -= (size_t)bytes_read;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And probably better to keep a `static const struct Conf default_config` around, for the purpose of overwriting.

---

Passing a `struct Conf` by value means that we are modifying the wrong structure.  Pass it as a pointer, so we can write to the caller's version.

---

Naming is inconsistent, with a mix of lower-case and PascalCase names.  Stick with one convention (preferably the platform's usual convention) to avoid making life difficult for maintainers.

Names such as `str` carry no useful information.  Prefer names that convey the purpose of variables, rather than their type.

Since `exist` is a boolean, prefer to initialise with `false` rather than `0`.

Prefer to use `sizeof` on objects rather than types.  That makes it easier to see that the correct size is being used in calls such as `read(fd, &conf, sizeof conf)`.

---

## Improved code

```
static int open_or_mkdir(const char *dirname)
{
    /* try creating it (harmless if it already exists) */
    mkdir(dirname, 0755);
    /* open could still fail, if mkdir failed or another process
       intervenes */
    return open(dirname, O_DIRECTORY);
}

static bool read_n(int fd, void *dest, size_t count)
{
    char *p = dest;
    while (count) {
        ssize_t bytes_read = read(fd, p, count);
        if (bytes_read == 0) {
            /* this will have to do to indicate file-too-short */
            errno = EPIPE;
        }
        if (bytes_read <= 0) {
            return false;
        }
        p += bytes_read;
        count -= (size_t)bytes_read;
    }
    return true;
}

int read_conf(const char *str, struct Conf *conf)
{
    int dir = open_or_mkdir(str);
    if (dir < 0) {
        perror(str);
        return errno;
    }

    const int fd = openat(dir, ".Conf", O_RDONLY);
    close(dir);
    if (fd < 0) {
        if (errno == ENOENT) {
            /* fine, and normal */
            return 0;
        }
        perror(".Conf");
        return errno;
    }

    errno = 0;
    read_n(fd, conf, sizeof *conf);
    if (close(fd)) {
        perror(".Conf");
    }
    return errno;
}
```

Comment: The only return value that indicates an error is `-1`. Also, if `errno != ENOENT`, it's pretty sure that a subsequent `mkdir()` will fail anyway. So I'd write: `int fd = open(dirname, O_DIRECTORY); if (fd == -1 && errno == ENOENT) { mkdir(dirname, 0755); fd = open(dirname, O_DIRECTORY); } return fd;`

Comment: I tend to write `< 0` partly out of habit (in Linux kernel code, return values tend to be a range of negative values).  Yes, we could avoid calling 'mkdir()` for most error cases - it's a balance between clarity and micro-optimisation, I think.  Thanks for the comments - they may provide OP food for thought.

Comment: Yeah it depends on what you want to optimize for. Personally I'd just always do an uncondtional `mkdir()` before trying to open; it's harmless, and even if it's unnecessary it'll have brought the inode into the filesystem's cache.

Comment: Oh yes - that first open attempt is totally unnecessary.  Why didn't I see that?  Updated to make it much simpler.

Comment: One downside is that we lose the `errno` that was set by `mkdir`.

Comment: As for the `memset(&Conf, 0, r)`, that was my mistake. Originally my code had uppercase variable names, but I tried to make them lowercase, but missed one.